# Show connected network shares (even those that aren't mapped) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

So I can use `net use` on the command line to see all connected network shares, including those that aren't mapped to a drive letter.

Is there a way to see this list in GUI form in Windows 7? I particularly want to see the connections that aren't mapped to drive letters but have authentication (perhaps because I browsed to the network share in Windows Explorer and gave it credentials).

Comment: I don't have a Win7 system in front of me to see if it's in the same place, or called the same thing, but Windows XP has "My Network Places" that does this.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found anything in the Windows 7 "Network and Sharing Center" for this.

Comment: You can use the shared folders manager (`fsmgmt.msc`) to view connections _to_ your computer from other computers, but I don't know of a way to view it for connections to _other_ machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a GUI version of `net use` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has the network icon on explorer on the left pane.  Sometimes the other computers on the network show up, but there are ways for those computers to block that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see which ones have been authenticated for, but you can use Network if file sharing is turned on and the firewall has it unblocked.

To view shares attached to other computers without the GUI, you can use `net view` to see the computers, then `net view \\computername` to see the shares on that system.

Comment: Well `net use` shows you whether or not it's connected or not which is what I meant when I said authenticated. For example, right now I have a share that's not authenticated, but it is connected. It says "Unavailable" with `net use` whereas the authenticated one says "OK".